# CSS Linear Gradient Color Darkens on Mobile iOS compared to Major Desktop Browsers

Tags: css, gradient, transparency, background-color, linear-gradients

I have discovered a strange problem about how **transparency** of linear-gradient background colors render on different platforms.

Two printscreens clarify the difference clearly. The first image is made on a popular desktop browser, the second image is on a popular mobile browser.

```
nav li{background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgba(220 170 80 / 1))}
nav li{background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgba(210 190 50 / 1))}
nav li{background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgba(180 190 90 / 1))}
```

---

On Windows Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Vivaldi and Edge it shows nicely as it should:

[image]

---

However on Safari iOS on iPhone mobile and iPad tablet the gradient band looks different: it starts out well, and it ends also transparent, but everything in between looks dark, dull and colorless! :(

[image]

---

**Question**:
What must be done sothat on mobile iOS the gradient behaves in exactly the same way, namly fades into transparency (no color defined, 100% transparency!) in the same as the other major browsers?

Comment: These are technically same browsers Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi and Edge!

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal They're different browsers. But they do all start with the same rendering engine; Chromium. But they do fork it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Safari: CSS gradient too dark when placed over similarly colored background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305348/ios-safari-css-gradient-too-dark-when-placed-over-similarly-colored-background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `transparent` value in CSS gradients. iOS assumes that "transparent" means "black transparent," or `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. Instead, switch it to a transparent version of the color you're using, e.g., `rgba(220 170 80 / 0)`.

Comment: Assuming there is no other "elegant" solution as of 2021, I accept the fact that it could only work by duplicating each and every color indeed. Helas there is no elegant/alternative solution than cloning, so I am accepting your answer. Hopefully iOS catches up some time in the future with the rest of the browsers... Thanks for the consice answer! The bounty is yours!